How to graph balls in metric spaces?
Metric space is given as: $d: \mathbb{R}^2 \times  \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
$$d((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|; & \exists k\in \mathbb{R} \text{such that} (x_1, y_1) = k(x_2, y_2) \\
|x_1|+|x_2|+|y_1|+|y_2|; & otherwise \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Sketch the closed balls:

$B[(0,0), 1]$,
$B[(1,2), 2]$,
$B[(1,2), 4]$;

I don't know how to do this. I can't find a source to learn the process from, all I found is the existence of 3 different metrics (Euclidean(circle), Manhattan(diamond/square rotated 45 degrees) and Chebyshev(square)).
Can anybody explain to me how is this done? I just need a step by step guide/thought process, I don't want you to solve this for me.
Thank you for your time and patience, cheers!

I like this question, this is the first metric I have seen where the shape of the ball with the same radius changes completely based on it's centre.

Start by throwing some numbers into the problem that work then see if you can find a pattern. Once you see the pattern try to prove what you've observed.

So what you want to do is to graph inequalities. For example, for (1), you want to graph the points $(x,y)$ such that $d((x,y),(0,0))=|x|+|y|\leq 1$ (it can't be the first case unless $(x,y)=(0,0)$ since $k\cdot 0=0$, and if $(x,y)=(0,0)$, then $d=0$). Obviously $|x|,|y|\leq 1$ so you just have to try the points $x,y\in [-1,1]$. Now you just plug in some point, say $x=-1$, then $y=0$ and so on and you are on your way.
So first you identify which points give you the first case and which the second, then you solve the repsecptive inequality as usual

I think you skipped the most important part that confused me (and potentially other viewers), setting up the inequality:
Closed ball is $B[(0, 0), 1]$, center is in $(0, 0)$, radius is $1$. So, we plug the center coordinates as second pair in the metric so we get $d((x_1, y_1), (0, 0))$ and then put the inequality to be $\leq 1$ because we want the inner area of the ball (and since its closed we put $\leq$ instead of $<$). I understood the reasoning behind choosing the correct case for equation and points $x, y \in[-1, 1]$. Thanks for the answer!

For the next example, how would picking the correct case go? $(x_1, y_1) = k(1, 2)$? What exactly should I do here?

This isn't that hard: Simplify those equations based on the centre of the balls.
For any ball centred at origin, that metric simplifies to $d(\vec{0}, (x,y) ) = |x| + |y|$.
For any ball not centred at origin, say centred at $(a,b)$, the metric is just $d( (a,b) , (x,y) ) ) = |x| + |y| + |a| + |b|$ except for two points, where the equation will be given by $d( (a,b) , (x,y)) = |x-a| + |y-b|$. You can figure out these points, and then very easily plot the balls.
Edit: Note that the above statement was for the boundary of the ball (i.e. "the except 2 points" part), not the interior of the ball.
